# How to write hive partitioned table with pyspark, with skip equal data column?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, hive, hdfs

In my project, I use hadoop-hive with pyspark.

my table created by this query.

```
CREATE TABLE target_db.target_table(
      id string)
    PARTITIONED BY ( 
      user_name string, 
      category string)
```

I get data like this.

```
user_name: john
data list:  # id, category
[('1', 'warrior'), ('2', 'warrior'), ('3', 'knight'), ...]
```

I want append this data to `target_db.target_table`.

first, i try this.

```
    columns = ["account_id", "category"]

    # creating a dataframe
    df_user_list = spark_session.createDataFrame(id_list, columns)

    file_path = f"{host}/target_db.db/target_table/user_name={user_name}"

df_user_list.write.partitionBy('category').mode("overwrite").parquet(file_path)

    for category in category_list:
        spark_session.sql(f"ALTER TABLE target_db.target_table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (user_name='{user_name}', category='{category}')")
        spark_session.sql(f"ALTER TABLE target_db.target_table ADD PARTITION (user_name='{user_name}', category='{category}')")
```

upper code is work.
but, in real data, i can't get `category_list`.  plus, i can't use 'overwrite', i need 'append' mode. so i cant use upper code.

now, i find one solution.

```
    columns = ['id', "user_name", "category"]
    
    result = []
    for item in id_list:
        result.append((item[0], 'test.user', item[1])) 
        
    # creating a dataframe
    df_user_list = spark_session.createDataFrame(result, columns)
    
    df_user_list.write.mode("append").insertInto('target_db.target_table')
```

upper code is perfectly work.
but, i think add `user_name` is so strange. it's same data, i think there are more efficient solution.

i want good solution like this.

```
    columns = ['id', "category"]
    
    # creating a dataframe
    df_user_list = spark_session.createDataFrame(id_list, columns)
    
    df_user_list.write.mode("append")
    .selectCategory(['user_name', 'test_user'])  # how to do this?
    .insertInto('target_db.target_table')
```

- edit

Sadly, @cruzlorite 's solution doesn't work.
I edit code like this, it works.

```
    df_user_list = spark_session.createDataFrame(id_list, columns)
    df_user_list = df_user_list.withColumn('user_name', lit('test.user')).select('id', "user_name", "category")
    df_user_list.write.mode("append").insertInto(table_name)
```

it looks better than my original, but i have one question. How does it work internally?

It works same to my original code? `user_name` columns is partition, so it's unnecessary in hdfs parquet file. spark can optimize it??

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
columns = ['id', "category"]

# creating a dataframe
df_user_list = spark_session.createDataFrame(id_list, columns)

df_user_list.write.mode("append") \
    .withColumn('user_name', F.lit(test_user)) \
    .insertInto('target_db.target_table')
```

P.D.: I haven't tested it.

Comment: cruzlorite> sadly, it doesn't work. I edit your code, it works. can you see my edit?

Comment: No, I can not. What was the error?